# UIViewController blur background turns into gray

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, blur, uiblureffect

I would like to use blur background for my view controller but as soon as the view is loaded, the whole thing turns into gray.

I present the view controller by performing a segue from another view, and in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the view controller, I implement the blur effect as given below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let blurBgView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight))
    blurBgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.insertSubview(blurBgView, at: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        blurBgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        blurBgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        ])
}
```

This is how it looks like

[image]

How can I implement a blur background for my view controller?

I use XCode 9.3, Swift 4.1

Thanks

Comment: first thing your code is fine and correct, actually you are used two light content thats why its shows gey , if you want to check use `view.backgroundColor = .red` and `(style: .dark)`

Comment: I can see the VC drawn with a blur background but it turns into gray when loaded. Instead of performing a segue to a new VC, I created a new UIView by using the same code and added it onto the subview stack. The result seems okay, it works fine. But I would like to use a VC and it still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present your view controller and set its `modalPresentationStyle` from your initial vc:

```
let newController = NewViewController()
newController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or, if you are preparing for the segue:

```
let newController: NewViewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController
newController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

And in the `NewViewController` class in `viewDidLoad()` add your code.

Comment: This gives a blur view on white background, so the underlaying VC is not visible, which is the whole point of a blur view

Comment: And you want to still be able to peek into the vc behind?

Comment: Well, i would like to get sth like the swipe up menu, which has the flight mode etc. in, in iOS. Without setting the background .clear , it simply uses a white background

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I have a tab bar controller, but the new VC appears under it. I need to fix that one as well